# How are multiple requests to Task.Run handled from a resource management standpoint?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have some code that I need to "fire and forget," in the sense that the calling code doesn't need to wait around for a response.

If I were to iterate a loop and call this 10,000 times in the span of a second, would I have 10,000 threads floating around, fighting for resources?  I have a nightmare of my machine instantly slowing to a crawl.

Alternately, does the thread pool manage these requests, and queue them for resolution?

Put another way, how easy is it to do something stupid with `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Just try it and it will be obvious how the ThreadPool works.

Comment: What are you doing with the 10,000 threads? What kind of work?

Answer (score 3):

So, when you invoke `Task.Run` it creates a new `Task` and schedules it on `TaskScheduler.Default`. That happens to be `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` which then queues that task to the `ThreadPool`. The `ThreadPool` uses a pool of threads (surprisingly) to slowly go through the work items. The `ThreadPool` manages its own threads internally and may create more of these when needed.

To your question:

> would I have 10,000 threads floating around, fighting for resources?

No, the `ThreadPool` usually knows how to manage its threads effectively and grows very slowly.

However, you **would** be allocating a lot of tasks that would wait there taking up space until completed. They may also hold on to other references (usually because of capturing) that take up resources as well.

---

By the way, if instead of the safer `Task.Run` you would use `Task.Factory.StartNew` and pass `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` you **would** be creating 10,000 background threads.

Comment: So, you're saying I can basically trust the thread pool to keep me out of trouble?

Comment: @Deane not really. I'm saying you shouldn't do that for reasons other than threads. Look at TPL dataflow's ActionBlock or maybe some other higher level construct.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Task.Run, you are queueing work to run in the thread pool. If you start a bunch of work, it can take a while to finish as you have limited computing resources. It's easy to bite yourself when running background tasks using Task.Run. It's best to understand the scenario and use the right tools for the job. If you're looking to process lots of background work, take a look at things like TPL, BlockingCollection and Concurrent Collections. Things like Producer/Consumer flows are the right direction, but all depends on what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In the case, I don't really care when the work completes, so long as it actually completes.  So the thread pool can sit on it for minutes, if it wants, so long as it eventually gets to it.

Comment: While you may not care to schedule a bunch of tasks, you may not be doing things the right way. What if by scheduling all of those tasks you utilize more memory than needed, introduce deadlocks, or have memory leaks? Solving things the right way on things that may not matter will make you better at solving things that matter later on.